# What is not feedable in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've tried the following code. But I don't find what is not feedable in tensorflow. Could anybody show me what is not feedable?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=-1 fileencoding=utf-8:

import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(3)
y = tf.constant(3)
z = tf.add(1, 2)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.graph.is_feedable(x)
    print sess.graph.is_feedable(y)
    print sess.graph.is_feedable(z)
```

Answer (score 4):

All tensors are feedable (including the constants, as you can see), unless they are explicitly prevented from feeding via [`tf.Graph.prevent_feeding`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#prevent_feeding) method. One can call this method directly or indirectly, for example, that's what [`tf.contrib.util.constant_value`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/util/constant_value) function does:

> NOTE: If `constant_value(tensor)` returns a non-`None` result, it will no longer be possible to feed a different value for `tensor`. This allows the result of this function to influence the graph that is constructed, and permits static shape optimizations.

Sample code:

```py
y = tf.constant(3)
tf.contrib.util.constant_value(y)  # 3

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print sess.graph.is_feedable(y)  # False!
```